# Convergence of $\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 \cdot (ln(x))^{\alpha}}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For which values of $\alpha > 0$ is the following improper integral convergent ?:

$$\int_{2}^{\infty}{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}\ \ln^{\alpha}\left(\, x\,\right)}$$

I tried to solve this problem by parts method but I am nowhere near to the answer.

Comment: I would be a bit afraid of the singularity at $x=0$ (independently of $\alpha$).

Comment: @mickep I typed my question wrong. its x=2. Thanks. Just editted. :)

Comment: OK, then it converges for any $\alpha>0$.

Comment: @mickep Can you give me some hints please...

Comment: x^{1/2}(\ln x)^{\alpha}\to+\infty as $x\to+\infty$, so it is greater than 1 if $x$ is large. Thus, your integrand is less than $1/x^{3/2}$ if $x$ is large...

Comment: Changing variable $x=e^t$ leads to $\int t^{-\alpha}e^{-t} dt=-\Gamma (1-a,t)$ where appears the incomplete gamma function. I don't know if this can be of any help to you.

Answer (score 5):

The integrand is always dominated by $x^{-2}$ and hence the integral is convergent for all $\alpha$. Just evaluate the integral by the fundamental theorem.

Comment: Well,  technically it's only dominated past $e$, but since we only care about the infinite tail,  that's enough

Comment: You're right, by "dominated" I somewhat implied an $O$ term.

Answer (score 3):

We have for every $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ (not only for $\alpha>0$)

$$\frac{1}{x^2(\ln x)^\alpha}=_\infty o\left(\frac1{x^{3/2}}\right)$$
and since the integral

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{3/2}}$$
is convergent since $\dfrac32>1$ then the given integral is also convergent.

Answer (score 2):

For $\alpha\ge0$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2\log(x)^\alpha}
&\le\frac1{\log(2)^\alpha}\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}\\
&=\frac1{2\log(2)^\alpha}
\end{align}
$$

---

For $\alpha\lt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_2^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2\log(x)^\alpha}
&\le\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)^{-\alpha}\mathrm{d}x}{x^2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty x^{-\alpha}\,e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[4pt]
&=\Gamma(1-\alpha)
\end{align}
$$